# Differences between matrices, bivectors and rank-2 tensors

Tags: matrices, tensors

I recently came across bivectors while looking into spacetime algebra, but couldn't understand their differences from the matrices, and from rank-2 tensors. While looking into bivectors, I found that they also follow the same distributivity laws as that of matrices. While being on the same question, I know that tensors are defined in vector spaces, but is it that matrices are defined on some other space, which makes it different from a rank-2 tensor? And if these three are completely different from one another, then why do we represent one with the other?

Comment: Do you know the general definition of an $(r,s)$ tensor on a vector space $V$ (for example as a multilinear map $T: (V^*)^r \times V^s \to \Bbb{R}$)?.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: such a multilinear map would be a $r+s$-rank (mixed) tensor

Comment: @janmarqz yes, I know, but the reason I asked OP is that without knowing the definitions, it's pretty hopeless to try to explain the difference. Clearly, tensors of type $(0,2), (2,0), (1,1)$ are different objects but in introductory courses the distinction is completely blurred (everything being introduced as matrices) which leads to all sorts of confusions (which is precisely what's happening here)

Comment: @peek-a-boo. . . d'accord, Almost nobody highlights the roll of vector duality

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes, i know that (0,2), (2,0) and (1,1) all represent a rank-2 tensor, which being covariant, contravariant and mixed, respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each square matrix $Q$ can be used to define a bilinear function on $V$, a finite vector space, through
$V\times V\to\mathbb R$ mapping via $(v,w)\mapsto v^{\top}Qw$ (matrices multiplication), hence $Q$ induce a rank two tensor over $V$.

A bivector is such a tensor but with $Q$ being anti-symmetric, that is $Q^{\top}=-Q$.

Now for other types of rank two tensors like the cases
$$V^*\times V\to\mathbb R,$$
or
$$V^*\times V^*\to\mathbb R,$$
similar mechanisms work:
if $f,g$ are in $V^*$ then
$$(f,w)\mapsto fQw,$$
and
$$(f,g)\mapsto fQg^{\top},$$
respectively. Transpose is used to match matrix multiplication since
it is a convention of representing vector as a column matrices and covectors (linear functionals) as a row vectors.
One last case is $V\times V^*\to\mathbb R$ via $(v,g)\mapsto v^{\top}Qg^{\top}$.

Comment: Does only square matrices constitute 2nd degree tensor?

Comment: Yes, bi-indexed quantities describe the components of rank 2 tensors for a single vector space, but talking about bilinear maps $V\times W\to\mathbb R$ with two vector spaces $V,W$ with different dimensions, you are going to need non square matrices.